# What is the next character in series?

Tags: logical-deduction, letter-sequence

What will be the next character in the following series?

**j , f , m , a , m , j , j , a , ?**

Comment: it's just too easy!

Comment: You underestimate the power of the darkside!.. I mean.. puzzlers!

Comment: its not easy until you think out of box

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The next letter is:

> s

Because:

> each letter is the beginning of a month in chronological order. The next month to be listed is September.

Comment: I will accept it after 12 minutes (stack.. Policy)

Comment: can you censor the answer? I would have tried thinking more about the question if I hadn't seen the answer right there, didn't even have to scroll. tried to censor myself but edit has to be at least 6 chars...

Comment: Sorry about that, @Sahuagin. I've moved the answer to a spoiler and removed any clue information from the visible text.

Answer (score 5):

The next letter is

> S

because

> the pattern is the first letter of each month and September is the next month after August

Comment: You are 15 second late than Ian MacDonald